# Merge [hard-disk-space] and [storage-spaces] into [disk-space]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

**[disk-space](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-space):**

> The amount of computer **storage space** on devices, **such as hard drive**,
>   floppy or USB flash drive.

I think we can merge [hard-disk-space](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk-space) & [storage-spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/storage-spaces) into [disk-space](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes. Thanks and done.

(If you have minor, obvious merges, just leave a message in the [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chatroom – will be faster I guess.)

---

Regarding your ninja edit: I haven't merged [storage-spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/storage-spaces) because [it's not quite the same](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/storage-spaces-explained-a-great-feature-when-it-works/), so I oppose to synonymizing it.

Comment: I thought it might seem too minor to be a meta post - will leave a message in the chatroom next time :) thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I edited the post (if you haven't noticed), by the way.

Comment: Noticed, see my edit :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't even notice all `[storage-spaces]` questions relate to Windows 8.

Comment: No worries, that's why we double check. I added a tag wiki just in case!